# Unlock automatically when android phone booted

Tags: android, android-framework

I had caught phone boot event.
On boot complete event I am writing following code

```
        KeyguardManager mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) mContext.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardLock mLock = mKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("MyApp");
        mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

but what happing I can able to see lock and after that screen is getting unlocked. But requirement is that lock should not be visible at all after booting.
My guess is that I need to make modification in framework somewhere in setting file.
But I don't know where to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did it by commenting following code in `KeyguardViewMediator`

```
private void showLocked() {

   /* if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "showLocked");

    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(SHOW);

    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);*/
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> but what happing I can able to see lock and after that screen is getting unlocked

You did not lock the screen. Hence, you cannot unlock it. `disableKeyguard()` is only used to reverse the effects of `reenableKeyguard()`.

> My guess is that I need to make modification in framework somewhere in setting file.

If by "setting file" you mean "Java, or possibly C/C++, source code", then yes that is probably the case.

> But I don't know where to modify.

StackOverflow is not a great resource for assistance with firmware modifications, sorry.